# Syntax error of DATA statement in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, numerical-methods

I have to compute few complex integrals and for this purpose I got from my supervisor old program written in Fortran 77. However I have few problems with it. Mostly associated with syntax errors of DATA Statement. This is a part of code with a function calculating real integrals:

```
FUNCTION  CAUSSA(F,A,B,EPS)
  IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
  external f
  REAL :: W(12),X(12)
  DATA CONST /1.0D-12/
  DATA W &
1 /0.10122 85362 9037 , 0.22238 10344 5337 , 0.31370 66458 7788 ,&
2 0.36268 37833 7836 , 0.02715 24594 1175 , 0.06225 35239 3864 ,&
3 0.09515 85116 8249 , 0.12462 89712 5553 , 0.14959 59888 1657 ,&
4 0.16915 65193 9500 , 0.18260 34150 4492 , 0.18945 06104 5506 /

  DATA X &
1 /0.96028 98564 9753 , 0.79666 64774 1362 , 0.52553 24099 1632 ,&
2 0.18343 46424 9565 , 0.98940 09349 9165 , 0.94457 50230 7323 ,&
3 0.86563 12023 8783 , 0.75540 44083 5500 , 0.61787 62444 0264 ,&
4 0.45801 67776 5722 , 0.28160 35507 7925 , 0.09501 25098 3763 /
  DELTA=CONST*DABS(A-B)
  CAUSSA=0.d0
  AA=A
5 Y=B-AA
  IF(DABS(Y) .LE. DELTA) RETURN
2 BB=AA+Y
  C1=0.5*(AA+BB)
  C2=C1-AA
  S8=0.d0
  S16=0.d0
  DO 1 I=1,4
  U=X(I)*C2
1 S8=S8+W(I)*(F(C1+U)+F(C1-U))
  DO 3 I = 5,12
  U=X(I)*C2
3 S16=S16+W(I)*(F(C1+U)+F(C1-U))
  S8=S8*C2
  S16=S16*C2
  IF(DABS(S16-S8).GT.EPS*DABS(S16)) GO TO 4
  CAUSSA= CAUSSA+S16
  A=BB
  GO TO 5
4 Y=0.5*Y
  IF(DABS(Y) .GT. DELTA) GO TO 2
  write(2,7)
  write(5,7)
7 FORMAT(1X,35HCAUSSA...TOO HIGH ACCURACY REQUIRED)
  CAUSSA=0.d0
  RETURN
END
```

The result of compilation is following:

```
 sample.f90:11: 

 1 /0.10122 85362 9037 , 0.22238 10344 5337 , 0.31370 66458 7788 ,&    
 1
 Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)
 sample.f90:17:

 1 /0.96028 98564 9753 , 0.79666 64774 1362 , 0.52553 24099 1632 ,&
 1     
 Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)
```

I use gfortran version 4.4.7. I tried to rewrite those arrays but the result is always the same. Although this function is not the best for integrating, I still need it. Without it, that old program is collapsing.
I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Can you try adding `-ffixed-form` to the compile command (or change the file extension from `.f90` to `.f`).

Comment: It looks like someone has tried to turn fixed-form source into free-form source just by adding free-form statement continuation markers (the `&` at the end of the line).  Without doing more (in this case) that's not valid.  Can't you just go back to fixed-form source, or do you need to fully convert to free-form?

Comment: Is this the original code? If not can you post the original one?

Comment: I only added Ampersands to the code. The rest is original.

Comment: Why did you add ampersands when there are already continuation lines ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compile this as free form source, there are two things you will probably need to change

1. I am pretty sure that labels are illegal in continuation lines, so they should be removed
2. gfortran will misinterpreted the spaces between sections of the floating point numbers, so those also should be removed.

Something like this:

```
   DATA W &
  /0.10122853629037 , 0.22238103445337 , 0.31370664587788 ,&
  0.36268378337836 , 0.02715245941175 , 0.06225352393864 ,&
  0.09515851168249 , 0.12462897125553 , 0.14959598881657 ,&
  0.16915651939500 , 0.18260341504492 , 0.18945061045506 /
```

should probably compile correctly [note written in browser and not tested].

Comment: My guess would be that what might appear to be one-digit numeric statement labels in continuation lines are, in OP's original code, actually in column 6, which makes them continuation markers.  SO's code-formatting doesn't respect the rules of punched-card layout.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Yeah that it probably right. But I think the problem might actual be in the OP's reformatting of the code from fixed to free format rather than anything SO did to it.

Comment: A frequently used method to make continuation lines work for both fixed and free form is to append the & at column 73 in the line to be continued, and prepend & in col 6 in the continuation line.  A fixed to free form conversion program should not have left the continuations in the form quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code was erroneously mixing both free-form and fixed-source format. Line continuations in free-form are performed by using a trailing ampersand character, `&`, rather than entering a character in column 6 of the following line. In fixed-source form, the first six columns are reserved for statement labels, with column 1 also used to indicate comment lines. In modern code, using structured control statements (such as `select case` or `if-then-else`) statement labels are uncommon. The first five columns are therefore wasted because they are rarely used.

Here is the same code in free-form and fixed-source format:

```
program main

    use ISO_Fortran_env, only: &
        compiler_version, &
        compiler_options

    ! Explicit typing only
    implicit none

    ! Variable declarations
    double precision :: a, b, eps, x

    a = 1.0d0
    b = 2.0d0
    eps = epsilon(a)
    x = caussa(my_func, a, b, eps)

    print '(/4a/)', &
    ' This file was compiled using ', compiler_version(), &
    ' using the options ', compiler_options()

contains

    function my_func(arg) result (return_value)
      ! Dummy arguments
      double precision, intent (in) :: arg
      double precision              :: return_value

      return_value = arg * 42.0d0

    end function my_func

    function caussa(f,a,b,eps)

      use ISO_Fortran_env, only: &
          stderr => ERROR_UNIT

      implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
      external f
      integer :: i
      real    :: w(12),x(12)
      data const /1.0d-12/
      data w &
        /0.10122853629037, 0.22238103445337, 0.31370664587788 ,&
        0.36268378337836, 0.02715245941175, 0.06225352393864 , &
        0.09515851168249, 0.12462897125553, 0.14959598881657 , &
        0.16915651939500, 0.18260341504492, 0.18945061045506 /

      data x &
        /0.96028985649753, 0.79666647741362, 0.52553240991632, &
        0.18343464249565, 0.98940093499165, 0.94457502307323, &
        0.86563120238783, 0.75540440835500, 0.61787624440264, &
        0.45801677765722, 0.28160355077925, 0.09501250983763 /

    delta=const*dabs(a-b)
    caussa=0.d0
    aa=a
5   y=b-aa
    if (dabs(y) <= delta) return
2   bb=aa+y
    c1=0.5*(aa+bb)
    c2=c1-aa
    s8=0.d0
    s16=0.d0
    do 1 i=1,4
        u=x(i)*c2
1       s8=s8+w(i)*(f(c1+u)+f(c1-u))
        do 3 i = 5,12
            u=x(i)*c2
3           s16=s16+w(i)*(f(c1+u)+f(c1-u))
            s8=s8*c2
            s16=s16*c2
            if (dabs(s16-s8)>eps*dabs(s16)) go to 4
            caussa = caussa+s16
            a = bb
            go to 5
4           y = 0.5*y
            if (dabs(y) > delta) go to 2
            write(2,7)
            write(stderr,7)
            !
            ! 7 format(1x,35hcaussa...too high accuracy required)
            ! Hollerith format specifier is a Fortran 95 deleted feature
            !
7               format(1x, 'caussa...too high accuracy required')
            caussa=0.d0

    end function caussa

end program main
```

Here's the fixed-form version

```
      PROGRAM MAIN

      USE ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, ONLY:
     1 COMPILER_VERSION,
     2 COMPILER_OPTIONS

C EXPLICIT TYPING ONLY
      IMPLICIT NONE

C VARIABLE DECLARATIONS
      DOUBLE PRECISION :: A, B, EPS, X

      A = 1.0D0
      B = 2.0D0
      EPS = EPSILON(A)
      X = CAUSSA(MY_FUNC, A, B, EPS)

      PRINT '(/4A/)',
     1 ' THIS FILE WAS COMPILED USING ', COMPILER_VERSION(),
     2 ' USING THE OPTIONS ', COMPILER_OPTIONS()

      CONTAINS

      FUNCTION MY_FUNC(ARG) RESULT (RETURN_VALUE)
C DUMMY ARGUMENTS
      DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT (IN) :: ARG
      DOUBLE PRECISION              :: RETURN_VALUE

      RETURN_VALUE = ARG * 42.0D0

      END FUNCTION MY_FUNC

      FUNCTION CAUSSA(F,A,B,EPS)

      USE ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, ONLY:
     1 STDERR => ERROR_UNIT
      IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
      EXTERNAL F
      INTEGER I
      REAL :: W(12), X(12)
      DATA CONST /1.0D-12/
      DATA W
     1 /0.10122 85362 9037, 0.22238 10344 5337, 0.31370 66458 7788,
     2 0.36268 37833 7836, 0.02715 24594 1175, 0.06225 35239 3864,
     3 0.09515 85116 8249, 0.12462 89712 5553, 0.14959 59888 1657,
     4 0.16915 65193 9500, 0.18260 34150 4492, 0.18945 06104 5506 /
      DATA X
     1 /0.96028 98564 9753, 0.79666 64774 1362, 0.52553 24099 1632,
     2 0.18343 46424 9565, 0.98940 09349 9165, 0.94457 50230 7323,
     3 0.86563 12023 8783, 0.75540 44083 5500, 0.61787 62444 0264,
     4 0.45801 67776 5722, 0.28160 35507 7925, 0.09501 25098 3763 /

      DELTA=CONST*DABS(A-B)
      CAUSSA=0.D0
      AA=A
  5   Y=B-AA
      IF(DABS(Y) .LE. DELTA) RETURN
  2   BB=AA+Y
      C1=0.5*(AA+BB)
      C2=C1-AA
      S8=0.D0
      S16=0.D0
      DO 1 I=1,4
      U=X(I)*C2
  1   S8=S8+W(I)*(F(C1+U)+F(C1-U))
      DO 3 I = 5,12
      U=X(I)*C2
  3   S16=S16+W(I)*(F(C1+U)+F(C1-U))
      S8=S8*C2
      S16=S16*C2
      IF(DABS(S16-S8).GT.EPS*DABS(S16)) GO TO 4
      CAUSSA= CAUSSA+S16
      A=BB
      GO TO 5
 4    Y=0.5*Y
      IF(DABS(Y) .GT. DELTA) GO TO 2
      WRITE(2,7)
      WRITE(STDERR,7)
C
C 7   FORMAT(1X,35HCAUSSA...TOO HIGH ACCURACY REQUIRED)
C HOLLERITH FORMAT SPECIFIER IS A FORTRAN 95 DELETED FEATURE
C
  7   FORMAT(1X, 'CAUSSA...TOO HIGH ACCURACY REQUIRED')
      CAUSSA=0.D0
      RETURN
      END FUNCTION CAUSSA
      END PROGRAM MAIN
```

With free-form, the concept of “significant blanks” was introduced.
In fixed-source, blanks were insignificant in most contexts. Here is a sample of a fixed-source statement showing what are now considered significant blanks followed by an equivalent statement without the blanks:

```
DO N = 1, MAX ITER S

DO N = 1, MAXITERS
```

Notice how we rewrote

```
  DATA W
1 /0.10122 85362 9037, blah blah
```

as

```
 data w &
 /0.10122853629037, blah blah
```